# Slow query when using group by on character varying field

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, postgresql-11

I have a schema of a table in postgresql and indexes created on it -

```
CREATE TABLE public.A
(
    id character varying(10) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    title character varying(2000) COLLATE pg_catalog."default"
);

CREATE INDEX id_index
    ON public.A USING btree
    (id COLLATE pg_catalog."default")
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

CREATE INDEX title_index
    ON public.A USING btree
    (title_index COLLATE pg_catalog."default")
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

Consider the 2 queries -

```
SELECT id,COUNT(id) FROM A GROUP BY id;
SELECT title,COUNT(title) FROM A GROUP BY title;
```

The execution time of 1st query is relatively very less than 2nd query. How can I speed up the 2nd query. Is there some other index I can try for large text fields?

Comment: You are using the whole table, indexes can help very little in this case. Do you actually need the whole data?

Comment: Please tell us the table size, and also what exactly are the two benchmarks you have.  Both your count queries have to potentially touch every record in the table, so an index would not even seem to offer any help.  Have you tried running `EXPLAIN` on both queries to see what is happening under the hood?

Comment: I actually need to get the top 10 results, so this will require querying all the records. I understand that the index won't help here.